# Flow of Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm a newbie to Hibernate . I cudn't understand the flow of Hibernate. Please clarify my doubts .

I have " HibernateUtil.java " with following statement

```
sessionFactory = new AnnotationConfiguration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
```

the configure() in turn runs " hibernate.cfg.xml " and returns "sessionFactory" object with the database connection properties.

I have created a table " STUDENT " under " UNIV "

Under "univ" java class package i have -

1) Student.hbm.xml (mapping to UNIV.STUDENT table)

2) Student.java (class with setter getter methods wrt to STUDENT table)

when i query " from univ.Student" in HQL Query 0 i get the table contents of STUDENT

but " from univ.Student" actually returns the " instance of Student class "

I am little confused here ....

1)when does the Student.hbm.xml file gets invoked

2)" HQL " interacts with " Java Class Object " whereas " SQL " interacts with " Database Table " .

Does " from univ.Student " hql command displays the table contents from the instance of " Student " class after the corresponding SQL command fetched the table contents using Student.hbm.xml mapping file

```
                                  (or)
```

the corresponding SQL command directly displays the table contents without any access to the " Student " class

Comment: I believe this question should be reopened. There are specific questions identified by number at the end of the post, and these questions do have specific correct answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The .hbm.xml files are loaded by configure(), which scans the classpath for .hbm.xml files with corresponding class names. You can also explicitly specify other .hbm.xml files, disable auto-loading, and do a few other things in your main hibernate.cfg.xml file. Personally, for smaller projects, I like putting all of the mappings for all of my entity classes in a single top level .hbm.xml file and specifying that in the cfg file.
2. Not exactly. The HQL is translated to SQL *first* (based on info parsed from the hbm file / annotations), so "from univ.Student" would end up as the SQL "SELECT * FROM STUDENT", and *then* Hibernate goes through the result set and populates Student objects (also based on info from the hbm file / annotations).